# Ignore errors on Execute Package task in SSIS

Tags: ssis

In an SSIS package, I have a For Loop Container task with the EvalExpression set to true (so that it runs forever). If any tasks inside the For Loop Container fail, then the package must fail -- except for the Execute Package task (that calls a child package). If that fails, then the parent package should move onto the next task.

I tried setting the MaximumErrorCount of the Execute Package task to 0, but that didn't help.
I tried setting the MaximumErrorCount of the For Loop Container task to 0, but that ignores the errors of all the tasks within the For Loop Container task.

Any idea how I can ignore errors on only the Execute Package task -- within a For Loop Container.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is to use the FailPackageOnFailure property for all the tasks that should cause the package to stop and set the MaximumErrorCount of the For Loop Container task to 0.

I got the answer here:
http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?&query=Ignore+errors+on+Execute+Package+task+in+SSIS&lang=en&cr=&guid=&sloc=en-us&dg=microsoft.public.sqlserver.dts&p=1&tid=6406db48-a2cb-4b0d-a124-4892e976a583

Comment: My Execute SQL Task in Control Flow has FailPackageOnFailure=False, FailParentOnFailure=False, MaximumErrorCount=1000, but it still stops all the package in case of error.

Comment: "Posted by Microsoft on 8/30/2010 at 4:43 PM --- If FailParentOnFailure is false, the parent will fail after the max # of errors is reached. If FailParentOnFailure is true, the parent will fail after the first error."  I found the above at this link's sublinks:  [FailParentOnFailure and MaxErrorCount - not functioning as I would expect](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/28ec9475-0d87-4904-9ccf-ba5496c5c570/failparentonfailure-and-maxerrorcount-not-functioning-as-i-would-expect?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

Answer (score 12):

A better way to do this is to go to the OnError handler of your execute package task and set the System variable "Propogate" to false.  This will stop the error from bubbling upwards to your loop container.

Comment: But I could not find this property in SSIS 2008 R2.

Comment: @KumarVaibhav see [here](http://datachix.com/2011/02/08/messing-with-errors-in-ssis-or-does-the-propagate-property-really-exist/) - you have to go to the `Event Handlers` tab and `...create a an 'OnError' event handler...`. After that, the `Propagate` system variable should appear in the scope of the selected executable.

Comment: Thank you! I would try that out.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Here's a [link](http://www.timmitchell.net/post/2013/08/05/continue-package-execution-after-error-in-ssis/) that explains this technique in detail.

Comment: Thanks, @mprost -- great link.  Also remember, when allowing a task to fail, you may want to change the type of arrow proceeding from it, to be on-completion instead of on-success.

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to "Event Handlers" on top
2. On the left side choose required "Executable:"
3. Go to "Event Handlers" on top
4. In the middle click on "Click here to create 'OnError' event handler for executable 'xxx'
5. Go to "Package Explorer", find newly created 'OnError' event -> Variables -> Propogate
6. In the properties change value to "false"
7. Done