# how can i continue for-each loop in SSIS when a task into for-each loop failed?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I  have package  SSIS package and  i work with SSIS 2008. I have start package which call other package   i want to read files in daily folder on WEB_DAV folder and insert records in tables and update some table and move this file to backup folder,  but  if one  file in daily folder has  error or one of task in for-each loop failed all the package failed.  i want if  any error occurred it save the log in log table and move this file to error  folder and  continue with remind files in folder .I can logging this actions but  i cant  move error file and continue working with remind files thanks in advance . 
[image: this is start package]

[image: this is archive correct files package and all these task are in for-each loop]

Comment: Look into `MaximumErrorCount`. Additional information Link [MaximumErrorCount setting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697538/ignore-errors-on-execute-package-task-in-ssis)

Comment: thanks for your answer but  i do these work but  it  dosent work for me  1 i create  on error and on failure event handeler with propagte false and set max error to 1000 but each data flow failed or other task  it failed all foreach loop   i dont know what is wrong in my  package

Answer (score 0):

Use the error event handler with the propagate variable set to false:
http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2014/05/continue-loop-after-error.html

Answer (score -1):

the easiest way it selecting the loop container and set the property ForceExecutionResult = Success.